# Installing Cordova latest version with Cordova CLI 3.6?

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I wonder how Cordova and Cordova CLI work together.

I want to know if I can download the latest Cordova framework version with an old version of Cordova CLI.
Do the framework and the CLI versions have to be the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your cordova installation (via npm) to the latest version, it will update the CLI.

```
 npm uninstall -g cordova
 npm install -g cordova@9.0.0
```